# Mostrar la categoria de productos como un elemento de una lista en un foreach en asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web

yo tengo una lista en el modelo de Ventas (sales) donde normalmente despliego todos los productos, pero ahora necesito desplegar tambien la categoria a la que pertenecen, pero solo una vez, por cada categoria de producto, como podria hacer esto?

Este es un ejemplo de lo que yo quiero hacer

```
Product          Quantity          Price

*Licors
Brugal           1                 500
Barcelo          15                700
*Fruits
Apple            1                 25
Banana           3                 5
```

Este es mi codigo, la descripcion que quiero mostrar esta en     item.Product.Category.Description

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="center"></th>
      <th>Serv./Prod.</th>
      <th class="center">Cant.</th>
      <th class="right">Precio</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>                  
 @foreach (var item in Model.SalesDetails.OrderBy(p=>p.Product.CategoryId))
  {
    <tr>
      <td class="center"></td>
      <td class="left">   @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Product.Name)</td>

      <td class="right">     @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Quantity)</td>
      <td class="center">   @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Product.SellPrice)</td>
    </tr>
}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Has probado con un groupby?

Comment: y como lo desplegaria ?

Comment: Quizás dos foreachs, en uno dibujas la categoría (que sería por lo que agrupas tus datos, y en el segundo foreach escribes cada item en cada grupo.

Answer (score 3):

Lo primero que vas a tener que cambiar es el modelo para poder definir jerarquia en los datos, algo como ser

```
public class CategoryModel
{
   //otras propiedades

    public List<ProductModel> Products {get;set;}
}

public class ProductModel
{
   //otras propiedades 

}
```

Luego podras definir un linq que cargue estas clases usando el `group by`

```
var model = (from p in db.Products
            group p by p.Category into g
            select new CategoryModel()
            {
              //propiedades
              Products = g.Select(x=> new ProductModel(){
                                            //propiedades
                                          })
            }).ToList();
```

este model lo usaras en la vista pudiendo iterar las categorias y los productos de forma anidada con un foreach dentro de otro

```
@foreach (var c in Model.Categories)
{
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">@Html.Display(c.Name)</td>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var p in c.Products)
    {
        <tr>
          <td class="center"></td>
          <td class="left"> @Html.Display(p.Name)</td>

          <td class="right">@Html.Display(p.Quantity)</td>
          <td class="center">@Html.Display(p.SellPrice)</td>
        </tr>
    }
}
```